# How to pass TestNG groups through terminal?

Tags: gradle, testng

```
build.gradle

  test {
        jvmArgs "-DisParallel=true"
        useTestNG(){
            suites testngxml

        }   
    }
```

when i am trying to run **gradlew clean test -Dgroups='sanityTests'** will not run tests in that specific group but will run all tests. Can you please provide some insight on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test {
    jvmArgs "-DisParallel=true"
    useTestNG(){
        suites testngxml
        includeGroups System.properties['groups']
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can pass by adding `includeGroups` inside test which is shown below:

```
 test {

    useTestNG() {
       dependsOn cleanTest
       useDefaultListeners = true
       includeGroups  groupName 

}
}
```